# check whether osx menu bar is translucent?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

We can change set Translucent menu bar from System Preferences -> Desktop settings.

Is there a way to read the this setting from some API or plist file and to get notified if user switches from Translucent menu bar settings?

If we do this,

```
[[NSDistributedNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
 addObserver:self
 selector:@selector(dockChanges:)
 name:@"com.apple.dock.prefchanged"
 object:nil];
```

We can be notified of changes done in system preferences. I am looking for something same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how we can can get the information about menu transparency.

```
NSDictionary *oldGlobalPreferences = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile: 
                                              [@"~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist" 
                                               stringByExpandingTildeInPath]];

bool bIsTransparencyEnabled = [[oldGlobalPreferences objectForKey:@"AppleEnableMenuBarTransparency"] boolValue];
```

Comment: This doesn't look Mac App Store compliant though.